# How do I display a full post, not just an excerpt?

Tags: posts, php, theme-options

I am a newbie, so apologies in advance if my terminology is off. I have purchased a theme (WP SmartStart) and I would like the posts in the blog to display fully, not just as excerpts. I read previous questions and answers, and found comments that said to exchange `the_excerpt` with `the_content`.

I searched through all the php files, but the only thing that seemed relevant was in the Functions.php file. I will paste it below, but I don't know how to change it so that the full post will display as I have not yet learned php.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code that I think needs to be changed:

```
if ( !function_exists('ss_framework_excerpt_length') ) {

// Sets the post excerpt length to 40 words (or 20 words if post carousel)
function ss_framework_excerpt_length( $length ) {

    if( isset( $GLOBALS['post-carousel'] ) )
        return 20;

    return 40;

}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'ss_framework_excerpt_length');

}

if ( !function_exists('ss_framework_auto_excerpt_more') ) {

// Replaces "[...]" (appended to automatically generated excerpts) with an ellipsis
function ss_framework_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {

    return '&hellip;';

}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'ss_framework_auto_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: There is an edit in the works that should take core of it but in the future be careful with your code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion... while I would usually give you a suggestion using the_content, I don't know how this code works into the rest of the theme.  So a quick, simple, and dirty fix would be to change the length to a crazily high number.  If you don't like that answer, I'm sure somebody will respond shortly with an answer using the_content.  Until then, try this:

```
// Sets the post excerpt length to 40 words (or 20 words if post carousel)
function ss_framework_excerpt_length( $length ) {

    if( isset( $GLOBALS['post-carousel'] ) )
        return 12000;

    return 12000;

}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'ss_framework_excerpt_length');
```

Comment: You gotta click the checkbox to choose the best answer!  :-)